# Django - where to place certain code

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'd like to have some code that deals with caching geocode results but I'm unsure on where to place it. A specific .py file? A custom Manager? A model method? View?

The piece of code would basically fire off requests, manipulate/store results in models and cache the data.

Where should I place this code that deals with many things (requests, models, caching)?

Comment: I'd write a plain python module/class to deal with fetching the data and cleaning it up and hook this up to a model manager which creates or returns model instances from the stand-alone module

Answer (score 0):

Since they're all related to geo, I would place it in its own module (i.e. `geo.py`) and then create helper methods and classes within it that you can import and use in other modules.  For example, and I'm just guessing at what your required functionality is, maybe something like this in `geo.py`:

```
class GeoConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, whatever, init, vars, here):
        # initialize connection

    def get_country_code(self, some_var):
        # fire off request and return value

class GeoCache(object):
    def store(self, key, value):
        # code

    def retrieve(self, key):
        # code
```

Then in some other module you can do something like:

```
from your_app.geo import GeoConnection

gc = GeoConnection(whatever, init, vars, here)
some_model.country_code = gc.get_country_code(some_var)
some_model.save()
```